# Laravel AJAX image upload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, form-data

Trying to get AJAX image upload working on Laravel 4 but having issues.

This is what I have:

The form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('class' => 'update-insertimage-form', "files" => true,)) }}
    {{ Form::file('image', array('class' => 'update-insertimage-btn', 'name' => 'update-insertimage-btn')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

And the PHP:

```
$createImage = Image::make(Input::file('update-insertimage-btn'))->orientate();
$createImage->resize(600, null, function ($constraint) {
$constraint->aspectRatio();
});
$createImage->save("user_uploads/cover_images/TEST.jpeg");
```

jQuery:

```
$('.update-insertimage-form').submit(function() {
  $(".submit-newupdate-btn").addClass('disabled');
  var rootAsset = $('.rootAsset').html();
  $.ajax({
    url: rootAsset+'saveUploadedImage',
    type: 'post',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $('.update-insertimage-form').serialize(),
    beforeSend: function() {
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if(data.errors) {
        $('.modal-body').append('<div class="alert alert-danger centre-text modal-error-message" role="alert"><strong>Error!</strong> '+ data.errors +'</div>');
      } else if (data.success) {
        $(".form-control-addupdate").append(data.name);
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
        alert('Something went to wrong.Please Try again later...');
    }
  });
return false;
});
```

I use this same exact code else where which works fine but not with AJAX.

The error is this:

```
{"error":{"type":"Intervention\\Image\\Exception\\NotReadableException","message":"Image source not readable","file":"\/Applications\/MAMP\/htdocs\/buildsanctuary\/vendor\/intervention\/image\/src\/Intervention\/Image\/AbstractDecoder.php","line":257}}
```

Any help?

Note, tried using formData and changed the jQuery to:

```
$('.update-insertimage-form').submit(function() {
$(".submit-newupdate-btn").addClass('disabled');
var rootAsset = $('.rootAsset').html();
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('update-insertimage-btn[]', $('.update-insertimage-btn')[0].files[0], $('.update-insertimage-btn')[0].files[0].name);
$.ajax({
    url: rootAsset+'saveUploadedImage',
    type: 'post',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if(data.errors) {
        $('.modal-body').append('<div class="alert alert-danger centre-text modal-error-message" role="alert"><strong>Error!</strong> '+ data.errors +'</div>');
      } else if (data.success) {
        $(".form-control-addupdate").append(data.name);
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
        alert('Something went to wrong.Please Try again later...');
    }
  });
return false;
});
```

But that is throwing the error:

```
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given","file":"\/Applications\/MAMP\/htdocs\/buildsanctuary\/vendor\/intervention\/image\/src\/Intervention\/Image\/AbstractDecoder.php","line":208}}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the form to the FromData contructor instead of trying to manually add the file to it.

```
var formData = new FormData($('.update-insertimage-form')[0]);
```